# sets with quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

My professor wrote the following theorems and definitions on the blackboard.

```
Def 1. A ⊂ B ⇔ A ⊆ B ∧ A ≠ B
Thm.1. A ⊂ B → (∀X)(X ∈ B ∧ X ∈ A)

Def.2. (∀X ∈ D)(P(X)) = (∀X)(X ⊆ D → P(X))
       (∃X ∈ D)(P(X)) = (∃X)(x ∈ D ∧ P(X))

Thm.2. (∀X ∈ D)(P(X)) is true
       (∃X ∈ D)(P(X)) is false
```

I understand the def 1 and Thm 1 completely, but I have no clue about Def.2 and Thm 2. Can anyone please explain them to me as simple as possible?

Thank you

Comment: Def 2 appears to be defining the notation $\forall x \in D : \phi(x)$, which is just shorthand for $\forall x : x \in D \to \phi(x)$, and likewise for $\exists x \in D$.  Thm 2 doesn't make any sense to me, maybe there's more context that you didn't include here?

Comment: hmm.. she also wrote "if D = ϕ" ....

Comment: They are exactly what my professor wrote on the board, I guess it's wrong?

Comment: You need to double check this with your professor.  It seems to have a lot of typos in it.

Comment: @BrianO I think Thm 1 would still be false even if $\exists x$ was used.  If $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \{\emptyset\}$, then $A \subset B$ but there is no element common to both sets.  I guess you'd need to assume $A$ is non-empty for it to be true.

Comment: @DanSimon Yes you're quite right. I wasn't even thinking about it clearly, thrown by he $\land$ and weirdness of it all :) Implicltly reading $x\notin A$ I guess, after mentally correcting $\forall$ to $\exists$. There's no way Thm 1. will be true, though, as it stands: it implies that $(\forall x) x\in B$, which is false for any **set** $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition 2 is defining a shortened form to express domain restrictions.

"Anything in D, makes P true" iff "Anything, *when* it is in D, *then* it makes P true".

$$(\forall x\in D)(P(x)) \iff (\forall x)(x\in D\to P(x))$$

"There's something in D, that makes P true" iff "There's something, that *is* in D *and* makes P true".

$$(\exists x\in D)(P(x)) \iff (\exists x)(x\in D\wedge P(x))$$

The important point is to learn which connective goes with which quantifier.

---

For theorem 2, you appear to be missing the declaration that the domain is empty ($D=\emptyset$). When the universe is empty then anything is true and nothing is true.

$(\forall x\in\emptyset)(P(x))$ is vacuously true.   It doesn't matter what $P$ is, since there is nothing in the empty set so there's no counter witness.

$(\exists x\in\emptyset)(P(x))$ is false.   Again, it doesn't matter what $P$ is as there is nothing in the empty set.

From Definition 2

$$(\forall x\in\emptyset)~(P(x)) \iff \underbrace{(\forall x)\underbrace{(\underbrace{x\in\emptyset}_{\textsf{false}} \to P(x))}_{\textsf{true}}}_{\textsf{true}}
\\[2ex]
(\exists x\in\emptyset)~(P(x)) \iff \underbrace{(\exists x)~\underbrace{(\underbrace{x\in\emptyset}_{\textsf{false}} \wedge P(x))}_{\textsf{false}}}_{\textsf{false}}$$